# Storing attributes with multiple values in relational database

Tags: mariadb, entity-attribute-value

I am storing product attributes in a relational table in a MariaDB database the following way:

I have a main table, called `Products` which provide the name, description, and other simple information about a product, and another table, `ProductAttributes`, with the following structure: `Id|ProductId|Attribute|Value` where `Id` is an autoincremented primary key, and `ProductId` is a reference to a row in the `Products` table.

I can store simple attribute value relations to a product in this way, say ie, `height`, `weight`, `length` of a product. My problems start, when a product's attribute, ie `color` can have multiple possible values.

I could add multiple lines to the `ProductAttributes` table when storing multi-valued attributes, ie:

```
1|yy|color|red
2|yy|color|blue
```

and from this schema, I could easily retrieve a single product's attributes, but I am having trouble on how to go forward when trying to compare two products based on their attributes.

Is there any other way to store multiple values for a single attribute in a relational database to maintain their searchability?

As of now, to find similar attributed products I am doing a similar query:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductAttributes base 
 INNER JOIN ProductAttributes compare ON compare.ProductId != base.ProductId
 WHERE base.Attribute = compare.Attribute
   AND base.Value = compare.Value 
   AND base.ProductId = 'x' 
 GROUP BY compare.ProductId
```

My problem is, that this query will return the products with a `red` and `blue` color, as similar to products with a `blue` color.

Btw, I can not change my attributes tables to a one attribute per column representation, because I do not know from the get-go how many attributes will I have, and even if I knew, I have way too many possible attributes and differences on each product category, to represent this in a traditional table.

A possible pitfall is, that I also want to compare products to one another with missing attributes. Ie, if a product has a length attribute specified, but another one has no length attribute, they could still be similar. Right now, to make this kind of comparison, in the background, I am transposing my attributes table, to a simple table, and on that table, perform this query:

```
SELECT b.ProductId as BaseProduct, s.ProductId as SimProduct 
  FROM tmp_transposed_product_attributes b 
 CROSS JOIN tmp_transposed_product_attributes s ON b.ProductId != s.ProductId 
 WHERE (b.attribute1 = s.attribute1 OR b.attribute1 IS NULL OR s.attribute1 IS NULL) 
   AND (b.attribute2 = s.attribute2 OR b.attribute2 IS NULL OR s.attribute2 IS NULL) ...
```

Comment: You are about to get into the quagmire of EAV.  Follow the tag I added.  Condolences.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following correctly for the product comparison, I like to use `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` to help find things like that, which may also help avoid having to transpose the data.

For example, given this sample table data:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from productattributes;
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | productID | attribute | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | yy        | height    | 5     |
|  2 | yy        | color     | red   |
|  3 | yy        | weight    | 10    |
|  4 | yy        | length    | 6     |
|  5 | yy        | color     | blue  |
|  6 | zz        | color     | white |
|  7 | zz        | height    | 5     |
|  8 | zz        | length    | 8     |

+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To find all similar attributes between the two, but has different values (removes attribute/values pairs that are the same) use a `NOT EXISTS` query to same table like so:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM `productattributes` pA
    ->  WHERE productID IN ('yy', 'zz')
    ->    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM productattributes pB
    ->                     WHERE pA.attribute = pB.attribute
    ->                       AND pA.value = pB.value
    ->                       AND pA.productID != pB.productID)
    ->  ORDER BY productID, attribute;
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | productID | attribute | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  2 | yy        | color     | red   |
|  5 | yy        | color     | blue  |
|  4 | yy        | length    | 6     |
|  3 | yy        | weight    | 10    |
|  6 | zz        | color     | white |
|  8 | zz        | length    | 8     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then to find attribute/value pairs that ARE the same between the two, simply remove the `NOT` portion of the query:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM `productattributes` pA
    ->  WHERE productID IN ('yy', 'zz')
    ->    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM productattributes pB
    ->                 WHERE pA.attribute = pB.attribute
    ->                   AND pA.value = pB.value
    ->                   AND pA.productID != pB.productID)
    ->  ORDER BY productID, attribute;
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | productID | attribute | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | yy        | height    | 5     |
|  7 | zz        | height    | 5     |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the query without the command line junk:

```
SELECT * FROM `productattributes` pA
 WHERE productID IN ('yy', 'zz')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM productattributes pB
                    WHERE pA.attribute = pB.attribute
                      AND pA.value = pB.value 
                      AND pA.productID != pB.productID)
 ORDER BY productID, attribute;
```

EDIT:
To cover the case where there is an attribute that is in one but not the other, then the `value` check of the query can be removed:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM `productattributes` pA
    ->  WHERE productID IN ('yy', 'zz')
    ->    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM productattributes pB
    ->                     WHERE pA.attribute = pB.attribute
    ->                       AND pA.productID != pB.productID)
    ->  ORDER BY productID, attribute;
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id | productID | attribute | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  3 | yy        | weight    | 10    |
+----+-----------+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: okay, but this will not return cases, as similar, where one product has a given attribute, ie, `color`, but another one, doesn't. Btw, I am searching for similar products, not similar attributes. Anyways, this query may help me in determining if they have overlapping attributes, when multi attributes are present.

Comment: Ok, see my edit to cover the attribute difference.